# Tell that webapp uses JSF without the need for an empty faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6, faces-config

Is there any other way to tell Java EE 6 app server that project is going to use JSF than having an empty `faces-config.xml`?

I'd love to do this somehow using annotations or maybe initialization code on appcontext. Having an empty `faces-config.xml` looks namely really ugly to me. I'm pretty okay with default configuration, just wondering if it's possible to drop the physical `faces-config.xml` file somehow.

Currently I already don't have any `web.xml` and I'm quite ok with that, so registering the `FacesServlet` manually is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only supported in JSF 2.1 and above, not in JSF 2.0. So you have to upgrade your JSF 2.0 libraries to JSF 2.1 or to target an apsperver which bundles JSF 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can remove it,in JSF 2 you dont need a faces-config.xml file unless you want to declare message resources,converters,validators,el resolvers etc.

Comment: well, I did that, and *.faces simply doesn't work, that's why I'm asking. with empty faces-config.xml everything works fine.